# Fetch API not giving response data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I have been trying to fix this but it gives me this: `ReferenceError: json is not defined`

this is my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function makeAFile(text){
    fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", {
        method: "post",
        body: 'hey wassup'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return json
}

console.log(makeAFile('nope'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused with how to return data from an async call. You do that using callbacks like this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function makeAFile(text){
  return fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", {
    method: "post",
    body: text
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
}

makeAFile('nope').then((result) => console.log(result));
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise);

EDIT: Provide a solution using `async/await`

```
async function makeAFile (text) {
  try { 
    const res = await fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", {
      method: "post",
      body: text
    })
    return res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

// Define an anonymous async function to allow await statements inside
(async () => {
  // this "await" here is important
  const result = await makeAFile('nope');
  console.log(result);
  // now result is store inside of "result"
})();
```

Comment: there is no need to create a Promise because `fetch` is already an async function.

Comment: @Anatoly You're right. I've removed new Promise allocation

Comment: but what if i want to store the var

Comment: @BRUH Do what you want to do with the result inside of the callback. You can store the result inside of a global variable but beware that the code after calling `makeAFile` will run right away and it won't wait for the callback to run so it won't have access to the updated values.

Comment: @BRUH You can use the new `async/await` syntax to get rid of callbacks and call async functions in a linear style. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: @BRUH Updated the answer with `async/await` code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to `json` outside `then` callback. Just make your function `async`, that way you will have an access to it and outer context code can wait till your function will be resolved or rejected:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function makeAFile(text){
    const res = await fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", {
        method: "post",
        body: 'hey wassup'
    })
    const json = res.json()
    console.log(json)
    return json
}
```

and call it like:

```js
try {
  const result = await makeAFile('nope')
  console.log(result)
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

or

```
const result = makeAFile('nope').then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: but await has to be in a function so i get the following error ```SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: You need to use 'async' keyword in front of function definition to make it work.

Comment: you can look at two examples of calls I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand, how async call works.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function makeAFile(text){
    fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", { // this is async call
        method: "post",                              // might give result later in time
        body: 'hey wassup'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return json                     // JSON is not defined and will be return just after 'Fetch' is called which is 'undefined'

console.log(makeAFile('nope'));
```

To make your code sync, you should use async await like this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function makeAFile(text){
    let res = await fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", { // await helps you to wait here to make your code sync
        method: "post",                              
        body: 'hey wassup'
    })
     const json = res.json()
     
    return json ;                                
}

try {
const response = await makeAFile('nope')); //use try catch to catch error
console.log(response);
}
catch (error) {
console.log(`Error ${error}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function makeAFile(text){
    jsonOut = ''
    fetch("http://bin.shortbin.eu:8080/documents", {
        method: "post",
        body: 'hey wassup'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => jsonOut = json)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return jsonOut
}

console.log(makeAFile('nope'))
```

you cannot access value inside a promise. Just check this code